# Bind selected dropdown option to variable

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have an `ngFor` loop that looks something like this (simplified so it's easier to follow):

```
<div *ngFor="let c of customers">
    <button class="save green-button" type="button" (click)="editCustomer(c.CustomerId, method.value)">Save</button>

    <select *ngIf="c.GrowMethodsAvailable.length" id="PerProjectGrowMethodId" name="PerProjectGrowMethodId" #method>
        <option *ngFor="let method of c.GrowMethodsAvailable" [ngValue]="method.Value">{{method.Text}}</option>
    </select>   
</div>
```

As you can see, there is a save button and a select dropdown with dynamic options. When I click the save button, I need it to send whatever value I selected from the corresponding dropdown list. I know how to bind the value to a variable I created in my class, but there could potentially be 10 different save buttons with 10 different values selected, so I assumed I will need a local variable for each select dropdown. I added `#method` to the select element and added `method.value` to my `(click)="editCustomer(c.CustomerId, method.value)"` function in the save button. When I attempted this I got the following error:

> Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

How can I bind the values from my selected options into the corresponding save buttons so I send the correct values for each one?

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your bindings is that repeating `#method` inside of the `*ngFor` for customers breaks the templating engine's handle on the select. To change it, and make it work we'll need to alter our approach and ditch template variable as they are statically defined:

We can abuse JS here for our sake, in your component add a property that will track selected items:

**component.ts**

```
selected = [];
```

In the HTML template we'll access that property in the button and the select:

```
<div *ngFor="let c of customers">
        <button class="save green-button" type="button" (click)="editCustomer(c.CustomerId, selected[c.CustomerId])">Save</button>

        <select *ngIf="c.GrowMethodsAvailable.length" [(ngModel)]="selected[c.CustomerId]">
            <option *ngFor="let method of c.GrowMethodsAvailable" [ngValue]="method.Value">{{method.Text}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/bWnlJfydPbUxeeI6a715?p=preview

Comment: I'm logging i.value to the console when I click save both in my app and in your plnkr and it is coming back as undefined.

Comment: Further reading (my apologies) indicates template variable bindings must be static. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4581#issuecomment-148786554